# i change the codebehind file, nothing happens

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

In asp.net WebForms I make any changes to aspx.cs file, nothing happens. R# and IntelliSense are not working too on that tab. I even can write 'blablabla' anywhere, it won't cause any errors.

Seems like VS just takes the file from some other source, not the project folder, though the "CodeBehind" attribute in .aspx is written ok.

I also have this problem:
[image]

The designer.cs is not in .aspx branch and I don't know how to put it back, maybe these problems are somehow linked.

P.S. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding? Right click on the solution in the Solution Explorer and select Rebuild All. Sometimes VS doesn't quite notice changes and will use old code until you explicitly build it.

Comment: Yes, tried to rebuild a whole lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the files (prefixed with index...) and re-create the index.aspx form anew :-)

Comment: There's 25 pages more with the same problem :(

Comment: Try it for one page and see if you can get intellisense working in the code-behind for that. This happened to me a few times and that was the only fix...

Answer (score 0):

If you opened it as a solution and not as a website you might need to compile after every change, but a better option, really, is to open the project as a website...